# Creating a custom action in a form that pushes/appends values to an attribute (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `User` and `Tag` model and they have a many-to-many association so an user can have one or many tags and a tag can have one ore many users:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy  
  has_many :posts, :through => :taggings
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribed_users, :source => :user, :through => :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user  
  belongs_to :tag
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  (Devise stuff)

  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribed_tags, :source => :tag, :through => :subscriptions
end
```

I just need to make that form and the controller action.
I can 'subscribe' the current user to tags by appending the tags to the `subscribed_tags` attribute:

```
current_user.subscribed_tags << Tags.find_by_named("food")
```

So this is what I got (the CAPS are the parts of the code that I don't know how to complete:

**users_controller.rb:** (actually I'm not very sure if this action should go int he user controller or post controller)

```
  def subscribe_tags
    SOMETHING_HERE
  end
```

**routes.rb:**

```
get 'users/subscribe_tags' => 'users#subscribe_tags', as: 'subscribe_tags'
```

**posts/index.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for SOMETHING_HERE %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label SOMETHING_HERE %><br />  
    <%= f.autocomplete_field SOMETHING_HERE, autocomplete_tag_name_posts_path, :"data-delimiter" => ' '%>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The user should be able to input one or more tags like this: `tag1 tag2 tag3` separated by a space and the form should only push/append the values (after submission the form will show up blank again). I think I need to do this `.split(" ")` somewhere.

I would appreciate any insights or  example code (Also, if there is any bad practice here please let me know).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. You want to know to do within the users controller to add the tags from the form to the user object being passed in? Could you clarify a little more? If you are doing this on User create, you could use the form params to add to the array.

Comment: @Justin Herrick No, I'm not doing this on user create. User creation and subscription to tags should be a different thing I guess. Basically, what I want is to create a form that triggers an action in the `users_controller` that has this: `current_user.subscribed_tags << Tags.find_by_named("SOMETHING_HERE")` and what the user types in the field should fill SOMETHING_HERE after submission (and the form should be blank again). An example of this is the tags filter in the sidebar of this site.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your storing the tags into the user's record. I think an easier approach would to create a "subscribed" table, which matches the user_id and tag_id's.

This isn't a solution, but I think you should checkout this out.
http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/
Great finishing touch.

Comment: I already did that, I only need to create the controller action and the form. I edited my question.

Comment: your need to create a form for a Subscription.new, and have the current user session as the user_id. Inside your create function, just loop through your results.